# Looking for a math function for my calculation (Arithmetic progression)

Tags: c#, algorithm, math

I think the solution will be simple and maybe duplicated with an other question. Sorry, if this answer will duplicate an other. I'm unable to find a solution because I don't know what I'm looking for. Well, I've got this simple function to calculate a full cost sum. How to simplify this function e.g. in an math function.

```
public int getFullCosts ()
{
    int initialCosts = 10;
    int currentCount = 3;
    int fullCosts = 0;

    for (int i = 1; i <= currentCount; i++) {
        fullCosts += i * initialCosts;
    }

    return fullCosts;
}
```

Comment: @Aybe This has a closed form solution.

Comment: Its AP (Arithmetic Progression) series of 3 x 10

Comment: You can of course factor out the for-loop but it's hard to imagine a production process with a cost function like this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This function is computing:

```
fullCosts = 1*initialCosts + 2*initialCosts + ... + currentCount*initialCosts
```

which is equal to:

```
initialCosts * (1 + 2 + ... + currentCount)
```

[the sum of the first `n` natural numbers is given by `(n * (n + 1))/2`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1_%2B_2_%2B_3_%2B_4_%2B_%E2%8B%AF)

```
initialCosts * ((currentCount + 1) * currentCount)/2
```

So here's how I would do it:

```
public int sumOfFirstNInts(int n) {
    return (n * (n+1)) / 2;
}

public int getFullCosts() {
    int initialCosts = 10;
    int currentCount = 3;

    return initialCosts * sumOfFirstNInts(currentCount);
}
```

Comment: Great! So there is no native math function (sumOfFirstNInts()) to make this work? Is there a name for that kind of calculation type? (e.g. like:  quadratic equation)

Comment: no problem with integer division, as the result itself is always an integer

Comment: @lin Not that I know of, and not that I know of. I just see it referred to as `Sum of First n Natural Numbers`. It's exactly what it says on the tin :p

Comment: @elias Oh yeah. Either `n` is even, or `n + 1` is even. The product of two evens is always even, thus `n * (n +1)` is always even

Comment: Sure. Another way of thinking about it, that it is a sum of integers, so must be integer.

Comment: @elias The end result is always an integer, but that's not my concern. My concern was that the numerator `n * (n +1)` could be odd. In this case, division by 2 would be truncating, and would cause a wrong answer. I proved that the numerator is even, so the division by 2 is always accurate.

Comment: @Alexander, we have two different approaches here, and both of us is correct. I'm looking at it from the opposite direction: once we know, that 1+2+...+n=n(n+1)/2, we can prove that the numerator is a multiple of the denominator because the sum itself is integer.

Comment: `>> 2` is dividing by 4 and thus wrong.  Using `>>` instead of a simple `/` is silly, that stopped being an optimization decades ago.

Answer (score 2):

You are essentially calculating:

```
fullCosts = (1 + 2 + 3 + ... + currentCount)*initialCosts
```

So you can just use:

```
fullCosts = initialCosts*(currentCount*(currentCount+1))/2
```

instead of using a for loop; because math!

Comment: Upvoted, thanks for your help. Dont be afraid if I mark the answer of Alex as right. His answer provides more information about solving this problem. Anyways, thanks.